# How do I set up a Generalized Additive Model in brms?

Tags: gam, brms

```
How do I set the priors for a smooth variable s() in the brms set_prior command for both the fixed effect portion and the random effect portion of a Generalized Additive Model that is incorporated in brms (a macro writer that calls STAN)? Mechanically, I can see that in the set_prior feature of brms, I need to insert something besides a flat prior for the smooth variable sDev_Yr_1, but how do I describe the single smooth variable when it changes throughout the range of values for Dev_Yr?

Here is the model:

Model_GAM <- brm(bf(Trended_Incr_PP_Def ~ Dev_Yr_1_Factor + s(Dev_Yr, k=3, m=2) +Cal_Yr_Time,
              sigma ~  0+ Intercept + Dev_Yr_6_Cap + Dev_Yr_10_Spline ),
             iter = 4000,
              prior= GAM_prior,
             seed= 8603529,
             control = list(adapt_delta = .99 ),
             data = Train_Triangle_All_Operation, family = lognormal())

Here is the summary from running the model:
```

summary(Model_GAM)
Family: lognormal
Links: mu = identity; sigma = log
Formula: Trended_Incr_PP_Def ~ Dev_Yr_1_Factor + s(Dev_Yr, k = 3, m = 2) + Cal_Yr_Time
sigma ~ 0 + Intercept + Dev_Yr_6_Cap + Dev_Yr_10_Spline
Data: Train_Triangle_All_Operation (Number of observations: 253)
Draws: 4 chains, each with iter = 4000; warmup = 2000; thin = 1;
total post-warmup draws = 8000

Smooth Terms:
Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sds(sDev_Yr_1)    14.27      6.99     6.67    32.76 1.00     3983     4393

Population-Level Effects:
Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
Intercept                 -0.77      0.27    -1.30    -0.24 1.00     7033     5186
Dev_Yr_1_Factor2           5.10      0.28     4.57     5.66 1.00     6507     4634
Cal_Yr_Time                0.01      0.00     0.00     0.02 1.00     8006     4830
sigma_Intercept            0.53      0.09     0.35     0.71 1.00     4214     4553
sigma_Dev_Yr_6_Cap        -0.33      0.03    -0.38    -0.27 1.00     4068     4369
sigma_Dev_Yr_10_Spline     0.09      0.03     0.03     0.16 1.00     3858     3521
sDev_Yr_1                  2.01      0.09     1.86     2.22 1.00     3677     3162

Draws were sampled using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
Warning message:
There were 5 divergent transitions after warmup. Increasing adapt_delta above 0.99 may help. See http://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#divergent-transitions-after-warmup

```
Here are the priors that were used when running the model:

prior_summary(Model_GAM)


               prior     class                    coef group resp  dpar nlpar lb ub       source
              (flat)         b                                                           default
  normal(0.02, 0.01)         b             Cal_Yr_Time                                      user
     normal(1, 0.95)         b        Dev_Yr_1_Factor2                                      user
              (flat)         b               sDev_Yr_1                              (vectorized)
              (flat)         b                                    sigma                  default
```

student_t(3, 0.1, 0.05)         b        Dev_Yr_10_Spline            sigma                     user
normal(-0.1, 0.05)         b            Dev_Yr_6_Cap            sigma                     user
normal(0.2, 0.1)         b               Intercept            sigma                     user
student_t(3, 4.4, 2.5) Intercept                                                           default
student_t(3, 0, 2.5)       sds                                                 0         default
student_t(3, 0, 2.5)       sds s(Dev_Yr, k = 3, m = 2)                         0    (vectorized)